# What is wrong f-string in Python?

Tags: python, f-string

- below code is my valid requirement.

```py
import numpy as np
a =np.array([1, 3, 0, 2], int)
b =np.array([5, 2, 1, 2], int)
print(f'{a > b = }')
```

- result is ok

```
a > b = array([False,  True, False, False])
```

---

- I wanna make inner function which have f-string style.

```py
import numpy as np
a =np.array([1, 3, 0, 2], int)
b =np.array([5, 2, 1, 2], int)

def myprn(text):
    print(f'{text = }')

myprn(a > b)
```

- result is not my requirement
- I wanna print 'a > b' instead of 'text'

```
text = array([False,  True, False, False])
#^^^ how to fix this requirement?
```

Comment: Your f-string syntax is wrong. Why do you end your curly brackets with `=`?

Comment: @SimonLundberg this is Python >3.8

Comment: This won't work because `a > b` is evaluated and saved as `text` before it is used in the f-string. What to do really depends on your use case. As is, your function does nothing, so you might as well use the print line directly. If the function actually is more complex, you could add a second argument where you pass a descriptive string and print that.

Comment: The only way I can think to make something similar to this work is `print(f'{text} = {eval(text)}')` and then passing the function strings with the expression, i.e. `myprn('a > b')`

Comment: @SimonLundberg This is valid syntax. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Comment: Oh, huh, I didn’t know about that. Been stuck in 3.7 for too long.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you for your tip. I have knew syntax eval() function. Your answer is fine and my requirement. I checked valid operation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @dEitY719 Please see [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/6045800) and be sure to read more about `eval` if you're actually going to use it. As mentioned in another comment, it would help if you gave context of what you're trying to do because solving it this way is not the best...

Comment: @ Tomerikoo Honestly, I can't understand exactly why using eval is a bad habit. I am currently in the process of learning and practicing Python, and I will save your advice and look at it again later. Thank you again for your deep insight. :)

Comment: @dEitY719 It's a security vulnerability. If a user or external actor has ANY way to control the text being evaluated, they can do almost anything. Even when you're sure there's no way, changes in the future may accidentally open a security hole.

Comment: @MatBailie It's a *POTENTIAL* security vulnerability.  For example, if you use eval in an tool that only you use, and only on data you produce and consume, then it's *NOT* a vulnerability.  This reminds me of email address "validators" that reject a plus sign in the local-part "because it could end up being eval'd" or some similar inane argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Thanks to @Tomerikoo.

- His reply gave me a hint. I was able to learn the movements I wanted according to his comments

*@Tomerikoo's comment*

> The only way I can think to make something similar to this work is
> print(f'{text} = {eval(text)}') and then passing the function strings
> with the expression, i.e. myprn('a > b')

Answer (score 2):

You can't, `=` in f-string is self-documenting sign which just prints expression before it as is. [Doc reference](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)